# Should magic quotes be on/off for Drupal 7?

Tags: 7

Should magic quotes be on or off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off. Currently it's non standard to set them on, and [here](http://drupal.org/node/2745) you have somebody with problems created by magic quotes on.